# Command Prompt: dir /s EXCLUDE full path but INCLUDE sub folders

Tags: list, batch-file, command, prompt, dir

I have a bit of a simple but annoying problem. I am making a batch file and I am using:

```
dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.mp3 *.txt *.res > sample.res
```

to get:

```
C:\Downloads\Sample1.wad  
C:\Downloads\Sample2.wav  
C:\Downloads\Folder1\Sample3.mdl  
C:\Downloads\Folder1\Folder2\Sample4.txt
```

But what I really want is:

```
Sample1.wad  
Sample2.wav  
Folder1/Sample3.mdl  
Folder1/Folder2/Sample4.txt
```

I want the sub folders included but I don't want the full path included. How can I accomplish this? Thanks.

*[EDIT: Realized for my purposes I apparently need a FORWARD slash for folders instead of a BACK slash]*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.mp3 *.txt *.res') do ( 
       set "$Path=%%a"
       set $path=!$path:%cd%=!
       echo !$path:~1!)
)>sample.res
```

**EDIT :** To have the `\` replaced with `/` :

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f  "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.mp3 *.txt *.res') do ( 
       set "$Path=%%a"
       set $path=!$path:%cd%=!
       set $path=!$path:\=/!
       echo !$path:~1!)
)>sample.res
```

Comment: Worked awesomely, a major thank you! Although I now realize a new issue. Anyway to have FORWARD ( / ) slashes instead of BACK slashes ( \ ) in there at all? Either way again, a HUGE thanks.

Comment: I know it says to avoid comments like "thanks" but doesn't seem right to let your help go un thanked so another HUGE thanks. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /B /S /A:-D *.wad *.mdl *.wav *.spr *.bmp *.tga *.pcx *.mp3 *.txt *.res') DO ECHO %~nG%~xG >> sample.res
```

Comment: Awesome, a thanks for the help! Any ideas on getting the file generated to use forward slashes instead of back slashes between the folders? Either way a thanks again. :-)